# X-ray default user agent

Tags: javascript, node.js, x-ray

I am developing Node-Js application and I am using X-Ray library and Request-X-Ray as a driver and I just want to know which user-agent by default X-Ray is using?

Answer (score 0):

X-Ray uses superagent internally, which defaults to **`node-superagent/{superagent-version}`** if it is not set explicitly.

You can see this [here directly in the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/blob/5d6e4b79da271dd10b5ea67b35701d1eff73dc09/lib/node/index.js#L118).

Comment: but I am using the request-x-ray library as a driver so it refers to the request library I think, which is not the same as node-superagent?